# AdMob TestAds do not appear

Tags: android, admob, android-logcat

I have followed the instructions on:

https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals#play (banner in XML)

I could create an add successfully on my mobile-phone, the problem ist just that my phone was not detected as a test-device.

The code of my xml file is:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-8720354845676054/3200XXXXXX"
          ads:adSize="BANNER"                                                                                           
           />
```

And the code of my activity is:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

       ....

    // Look up the AdView as a resource and load a request.
    AdView adView = (AdView)this.findViewById(R.id.adView); 

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
        .addTestDevice("3F094BCA6B8CBCB54B5D71810E2XXXX")
        .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

The problem is now that I do not receice any test ads. The logcat also has the output "03-03 13:17:19.638: I/Ads(20795): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("3F094BCA6B8CBCB54B5D71810E2XXXX") to get test ads on this device.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the permissions for INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE set? Otherwise AdMob can not do it's job.

Comment: Do you have internet permissions set up? If I remember right, even the test ads need internet permission

Comment: I have done both permissions. I just guessed the above shown code was wrong...